# javascript dynamically create select tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parent-child, html-select

Please forgive if this is duplicated elsewhere, I don't know what its called, so not sure how to look for it!

I am working on creating a javascript / jquery / ajax html page editor, where I can select and add html elements via mostly mouse clicks. To track the elements, I am keeping them in a select dropdown element. Firstly, is there anything open source out there, that already does this? If not, the problem I am having is how to track parent / child elements, div tags inside other div tags etc. What I have so far, to handle adding an element, will add a child, but I want to add more functionality, like adding a child, to another child. Here is my code so far:

```
 $("#make_child").click(function() {
     var selected_element = $('#elements option:selected').val();
     var element_index = $("#elements").prop('selectedIndex');

    if( element_index > 1 ){
        var index_count = element_index -1;
        var re = selected_element.split("|");
        var parent_element = re[0];
        var se = re[1];

        var v = $('#elements option').eq( index_count ).val();
        var re = v.split("|");

        var previous_element_parent = re[0];
        var previous_element = re[1];

        //element is not child
        if( parent_element == 0){
            while( previous_element_parent != 0 && index_count > 0 ){
                index_count --;
                v = $('#elements option').eq( index_count ).val();
                re = v.split("|");
                previous_element_parent = re[0];
                previous_element = re[1];
            }

            if( previous_element_parent == 0 ){
                parent_element = previous_element;
            }else parent_element = previous_element_parent;
        }else{
            if( previous_element_parent != 0 && parent_element != previous_element )    parent_element = previous_parent;
            else if( previous_element_parent != 0 ) parent_element = previous_element_parent;
            else parent_element = previous_element;
        }

        $.post( "gpp.php", { 
            what : "create_child",
            parent_element : parent_element,
            selected_element : se
        }, 
        function( data ){ 
            var r = data.split("|");
            var is_child = "";
        $("#response").html( "Adopting element: ((" + data + "))" );
            if( r[0] == -1){
                $("#response").html( "Error: " + data );
            }
            else{
                $('#elements option').eq( element_index ).val( r[2] + "|" + r[0] );

                if( previous_element_parent != 0 && parent_element == previous_element )    is_child = "<?php print ICON_CHILD; ?>";

                $('#elements option').eq( element_index ).html( is_child + "<?php print ICON_CHILD; ?>" + r[3] );
            }
        });
    }
    else{
        $("#response").html( $("#response").html() + ", *Error, can't make child, there is no element available to adopt it!" );
    }
 });
```

The dropdown option values track the element id's as two values seperated via a |, for example a parent element with an id of 1, and a child element with an id of 2, would be:

```
 <option val="1|2">Child element</option>
```

Added jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zothen/5sp50eow/

Making a child works, but how do I make a child of a child?

Comment: Please provide a working example in JSFiddle, the code you have provided is only partial

Comment: Added to original post!